# JS - Read Data Between XML Tags

Tags: javascript, split

I simply need to extract some info between two tags, in this case, `<title>`

For example:

```
...
<title>I Need This!</title>
...
```

And I simply need to be able to get the information between the tags. I was thinking using `split()`, however, I haven't been able to figure out how to cut all data before and after, and just catch the stuff in the title tags. As you can tell, I'm a beginner with text formatting. Thanks!

EDIT: An example of the type of file I'm looking through is here: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/http://youtu.be/_OBlgSz8sSMg?v=2

I'm simply trying to take what's in the title tags to get the title of the video.

Comment: Are you parsing HTML text or do you want to pull the title from the current page? If the former, I would recommend a simple regular expression to strip away the HTML tags.

Comment: Use an XML parser. Or do you have something specific?

Comment: It's specific. I get a value returned, which is a huge text (the XML code). Then I parse the text, searching for the title tags, and then I collect the value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var text = '<title>I Need This!</title>',
    match = text.match(/<title>([^<]*)<\/title>/),
    youGotThis = match[1];
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RPbSE/

Comment: I don't know for sure, since I've not used `match` before, but will this return all text between the title tags, or just "I Need This"

Comment: @JTApps - I updated it. It should now be getting anything inside those tags. Try it in the fiddle.

Comment: Works just fine now, thanks for the help! Answer can accept in 2 min. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

DOM works on XML just as well as on HTML, so a simple

```
var titleNodeList = yourXMLDocument.getElementsByTagname('title');
var firstTitle = titleNodeList[0];
var titleTextNode = firstTitle.firstChild;
alert(titleTextNode);
```

should do.

Comment: It's not actually an XML doc, this is a string, a value, that  am parsing from